# How to stop validating a datagridview cell if a user tries to select a cell in previous columns of the current row C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview that contains 5 columns, in the code I also added datagridview1__CellValidating event as well.
Currently when a user tries to modify a cell value and then leaves the cell the datagridview1__CellValidating event is triggered but I don't want datagridview1__CellValidating to be always triggered.

In my case, lets say that I am trying to modify the value of a column 3 and then I click\select the cell in the column 2 or column 1 of the current row. In this case I don't want datagridview1__CellValidating to be triggered. Is there any condition that I can add in datagridview1__CellValidating?

But I want datagridview1__CellValidating to be executed after modifying the value of the column 2 if I try to select the cell of a column 4 or 5 in my current row.

Is there any solution\workaround for this?

Comment: The `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` of the CellValidating event handler can be used to determine which Cell is being validated. You can just `return` if you don't want to validate a Cell that belongs to a specific Column. If that's what you mean. -- Of course CellValidating is raised before CellValueChanged.

Comment: lets say CellValidating is triggered on column 3, how do I know that the user is trying to select column 2 or column 5 in CellValidating event?

Comment: You apparently don't care, given the conditions you have set in the question. Is there a typo? -- Why don't you describe what you're trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it?

Comment: @Jimi sorry if the question is confusing, let me rephrase it. If I'm in column 3 and after Editing the value I want to select Column 2 (in the current row) in this case I DON'T want Cell_Validating event to be executed for column 3, but if after editing column 3 I want to select Column 4, in this case I want Cell_Validating Event to be executed for column 3.

Answer (score 0):

use `CellValidating` event in `DataGridView` and Cancel editing for Column 1 and 2.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellCollection cells = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells;
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
    {
       if(cell.ColumnIndex == 0 || cell.ColumnIndex == 1)
       {
          e.Cancel = true;
       }
    }
}
```

And override the button to close the form because with `e.Cancel = true` you can not close the form.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = false;
   base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```